# Save array from JSON in user default and read array values back

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm retrieving a JSON dict with the following structure:

```
"SITES": [
    {
    "NAME": “ALICE LANE”,
    "WEBSITEAPPID": “XYZ”
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm saving that straight into user defaults like this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(JSON(dict as Any)["SITES"].stringValue, forKey: "adminSites")
```

I know there is data in the JSON because the below code provides two rows of array data:

```
if let arraySites = dict?["SITES"] as? [[String: Any]] {
  for sitesDetails in arraySites {
    print(sitesDetails["NAME"] as Any)
    print(sitesDetails["WEBSITEAPPID"] as Any)
  }
}
```

When I try print the user default data count, I get 0

```
let defaultAdminSites = defaults.object(forKey: "adminSites") as? [String] ?? [String]()
print(defaultAdminSites.count)
```

Why am I getting 0 results? How would get the array row details if I did for ["NAME"] and ["WEBSITEAPPID"]?

Comment: you can convert response into data to save it into the userdefaults.

Comment: Your mistake is `stringValue`, as `SITES ` is an array you have to write `["SITES"].arrayValue`, however drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable` as suggested in Gereon's answer..

Comment: When you save to UserDefaults you try the ```stringValue``` which returns a ```String```, but when you read from UserDefaults, you try to cast it into ```[String]```, which is an array of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a model object and `Codable` to avoid all those casts:

```
struct Model: Codable {
    let sites: [Site]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sites = "SITES"
    }
}

struct Site: Codable {
    let name, websiteAppid: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "NAME"
        case websiteAppid = "WEBSITEAPPID"
    }
}

// write to defaults
let model = Model(sites: [Site(name: "foo", websiteAppid: "bar")])
do {
    let siteData = try JSONEncoder().encode(model)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(siteData, forKey: "adminSites")
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// read from defaults
if let siteData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "adminSites") {
    do {
        let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: siteData)
        for site in model.sites {
            print(site.name, site.websiteAppid)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gereon. Where does my JSON(dict as Any)["SITES"] fit in the above code?

Comment: Updated my answer to include printing values

Comment: So I need to populate my JSON result in that struct as now it's printing your entry: FOO and BAR?

Comment: Yes, the `let model = Model(...)` line is just an example for the writing part.

Answer (score -1):

UserDefault Save Json Response

```
let result = jsonDict["SITES"] as? NSArray ?? []

let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: result, requiringSecureCoding: false)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "adminSites")
```

Get UserDefault data

```
let result = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "adminSites")
    if result != nil{
      let data = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(result!) as? NSArray ?? []
      print("Current User Details : - \(data)")
}
```

Comment: *Objective-c-ish* `NSDictionary` – which is wrong anyway as the object is an array –  and `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` are discouraged for simple JSON data in Swift.

Comment: @vadian you can decalre array if like json response in array getting. in my side json response getting nsdictionary data i have declare NSDictionary. Whats worng in my code and why my answer downvote??

Comment: As I said in my first comment don't use NS... collection types in Swift at all, your code does not work because the object for key `SITES` is an array and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` is inappropriate for lightweight data like JSON in Swift.